# Any way to list all apps in the google play store in parsable format?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824478/api-to-list-all-apps-in-the-games-category-or-any-other-category-in-the-apple) post regarding the Apple iTunes App store, would there be any way to find all the apps on the Google Play store?

Are there any APIs available or a simple page like the apple one with lots of hyperlinks? Or an RSS Feed?

Any portal I can find into the google play store seems very interactive, and not really a complete list, but lots of 'top' lists of apps/games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a paid service called [42Matters](https://42matters.com).

They provide an API that you can call for a subscription fee.